# Unable to hide the navigation toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

Other solutions do not seem to be working.

I am using a MasterView application just in case that is important.

I want on the 'detailViewController' for there to be no navigation bar, and also no navigation bar on the subsequent ViewControllers that I use a 'show' segue to get to.

Here is the DetailViewController:

```
Class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
configureView()
}

configureView() {
// Some UI Stuff
}


}
```

The navigation bar is still there.

In the MasterViewController this is the prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {


            if isFiltering() == true {
                let building = filteredBuildings[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailBuilding = building
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                rating = filteredBuildings[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!].rating
                print("rating was changed to \(rating)")

            } else {
                let building = buildings[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailBuilding = building
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                rating = buildings[indexPath.row].rating
                print("rating was changed to \(rating)")

            }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding navigation bar toolbar is different from hiding the navigation bar itself. If you want to hide the toolbar you could try what @Anbu.karthik suggested in the comments. However, if you want to **hide** the **navigation bar**, you need to use this *instead*.

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: This is what I already have in the viewDidLoad function, it does not work.

Comment: @RufusV it’s certainly not what you have in your question.

Comment: my apologies. I will try it soon.

Answer (score 1):

self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)